# Sprite from SKScene not running actions

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

In SpriteKit on iOS I thought it would be convenient to create sprites in a Scene Editor (in a scene not being presented) and then pull them in via code and add actions programmatically.

Unfortunately, I found that my actions run fine when I create a SKSpriteNode from scratch in code, but they do not run at all when I pull them in from another SKScene that is not the one presenting... Unless I have a breakpoint in the code, then the actions execute.

It says it has the added actions (`hasActions() == true`), it just doesn't run them.

Xcode 15, iOS target

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: @LucaAngeletti It was code like this where I'd get the sprite. I'd add actions after.
  guard let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: sceneNamed) else {
   print("Could not load '\(sceneNamed)'")
   return nil
  }
  guard let sprite = scene.childNode(withName: name) as? SKSpriteNode else {
   print("Could not find '\(name)' in '\(sceneNamed)'.")
   return nil
  }

Comment: And you confirm all of these `guard(s)` do succeed?

Comment: Yes, they succeed.

Comment: Unfortunately, without seeing the full code you are using I don’t think I can help.